# RxJava longer time interval period depended on current emission number

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Suppose there is a time interval Observable, which emit Long items every one second. How to enlarge that time period in connection to current emission number?

So for example for first 4 emissions it should emit items every second, but after that it should emit items every 3 seconds?

Is this possible to achive?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `switchMap()` operator to set the delay interval depending on the emission number.

```
observable
  .zipWith( Observable.range(20_000), new Pair<>(item, itemNumber ))
  .switchMap( pair -> Observable.just( pair.getFirst() )
                        .delay( emissionDelay( pair.getSecond() ), units )
  ...
```

The `zipWith()` operator generates an item paired with its emission number, while `switchMap()` creates a new observable whose delay is set by a function, `emissionDelay()`, that is given the emission number to compute the delay in `units`.